How to get the connected network name through app android 10 and above
fun getCurrentSsidForAndroidQAndAbove(context: Context): String? {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
        val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        if (networkCapabilities != null && networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            val wifiManager =
                context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
            return wifiInfo.ssid
        } else {

        }
        return null
    }

Iam using this code to find out what is the network connected. It is working fine for wifi networks, but when i connected to wifi enabled device using NetworkCallback network coming always null. can some one help me out how to get app connected network.
Main approach is to compare the connectivity and has to perform validations.
